# Функция fontsStyle не работает, взято с видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jU88mLuLWlk&list=WL&index=2&t=4964s

Tags: javascript, gulp

*fonts.js*

```
export const fontsStyle = () => {
//Файл стилей подключения шрифтов
let fontsFile = `${app.path.srcFolder}/scss/fonts.scss`;
//Проверяем, существуют ли файлы шрифтов
fs.readdir(app.path.build.fonts, function(err, fontsFiles){
    if(fontsFiles) {
        //Проверяем, существует ли файл стилей для подключения шрифтов
        if(!fs.existsSync(fontsFile)) {
            //Если файла нет, создаём его
            fs.writeFile(fontsFile, '', cb);
            let newFileOnly;
            for (var i = 0; i < fontsFiles.length; i++) {
                //Записываем подключения шрифтов в файл стилей
                let fontFileName = fontsFiles[i].split('.')[0];
                if (newFileOnly !== fontFileName) {
                    let fontName = fontFileName.split('-')[0] ? fontFileName.split('-')[0] : fontFileName;
                    let fontWeight = fontFileName.split('-')[1] ? fontFileName.split('-')[1] : fontFileName;
                    if (fontWeight.toLowerCase() === 'thin') {
                        fontWeight = 100;
                    } else if (fontWeight.toLowerCase() === 'extralight') {
                        fontWeight = 200;
                    } else if (fontWeight.toLowerCase() === 'light') {
                        fontWeight = 300;
                    } else if (fontWeight.toLowerCase() === 'medium') {
                        fontWeight = 500;
                    } else if (fontWeight.toLowerCase() === 'semibold') {
                        fontWeight = 600;
                    } else if (fontWeight.toLowerCase() === 'bold') {
                        fontWeight = 700;
                    } else if (fontWeight.toLowerCase() === 'extrabold' || fontWeight.toLowerCase() === 'heavy') {
                        fontWeight = 800;
                    } else if (fontWeight.toLowerCase() === 'black') {
                        fontWeight = 900;
                    } else {
                        fontWeight = 400;
                    }
                    fs.appendFile(fontsFile, `@font-face{\n\tfont-family: ${fontName};\n\tfont-display: swap;\n\tsrc: url("../fonts/${fontFileName}.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/${fontFileName}.woff") format("woff");\n\tfont-weight: ${fontWeight};\n\tfont-style: normal;\n}\r\n`, cb);
                    newFileOnly = fontFileName;
                }
            }
        } else {
            //Если файл есть, выводим сообщение
            console.log("Файл scss/fonts.scss уже существует. Для обновления файла нужно его удалить!");
        }
    }
});
return app.gulp.src(`${app.path.srcFolder}`);
function cb() { }

}
```

*gulpfile.js*

```
import gulp from "gulp";
import { path } from "./gulp/config/path.js";
import { plugins } from "./gulp/config/plugins.js";

global.app = {
    path: path,
    gulp: gulp,
    plugins: plugins,
}

import { copy } from "./gulp/tasks/copy.js";
import { reset } from "./gulp/tasks/reset.js";
import { html } from "./gulp/tasks/html.js";
import { server } from "./gulp/tasks/server.js";
import { scss } from "./gulp/tasks/scss.js";
import { js } from "./gulp/tasks/js.js";
import { images } from "./gulp/tasks/images.js";
import { otfToTtf, ttfToWoff, fontsStyle } from "./gulp/tasks/fonts.js";

function watcher(){
    gulp.watch(path.watch.files, copy)
    gulp.watch(path.watch.html, html)
    gulp.watch(path.watch.scss, scss)
    gulp.watch(path.watch.js, js)
    gulp.watch(path.watch.images, images)
}

const fonts = gulp.series(otfToTtf, ttfToWoff, fontsStyle);

const mainTasks = gulp.series(fonts, gulp.parallel(copy, html, scss, js, images));

const dev = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, gulp.parallel(watcher, server));

gulp.task('default', dev);
```

Ошибка в терминале:

> Error: File not found with singular glob: C:/Users/Пользователь/Desktop/gulp/undefined (if this was purposeful, use `allowEmpty` option.

Comment: больше всего похоже на опечатку где то. проверьте все пути

Comment: Проверил, вроде все так как должно быть